# Is there a java API for downloading videos from youtube?

Tags: java, video, download, youtube

I know that the YouTube Java API doesn't provide functionality for downloading a video from youtube. However, is there any way to download a youtube video given the browser url with Java and save to a file? I'm looking for something along these lines:

```
URL videoURL = getVideoURL();
// videoURL is input from user, as in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfjghdjogdjgh
YoutubeVideo videoDownload = new YoutubeVideo(videoURL);
OutputStream outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(getOutFile()));
//getOutfile gets file provided by user
InputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(videoDownload.getInputStream());
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int n;
while ((n = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
outStream.close();
inStream.close();
```

Comment: You can't do it without violating YouTube's [Terms of Service.](http://www.youtube.com/t/terms)

Comment: @Robert Harvey I'm not distributing it, it is for personal use.

Comment: The TOS doesn't make a distinction between personal use and commercial use.

Comment: @Robert I don't think this question is too localized. This question would certainly help me and is relevant to the whole world for many years to come and thousands of people use youtube, making it not too narrow. Youtube video downloaders aren't uncommon on Cydia for the iPhone.

Comment: You can try [https://github.com/axet/vget](https://github.com/axet/vget) api, it works very well for me.